How to access TS Server log?
I cannot get the TS Server logging to work for my build script. I need it as I want to learn how to make a plugin for TypeScript.
The VS Code logs won't do, so no use pointing me to the Open TS Server log command.
If I understand correctly, I need to set the TTS_LOG environment variable before running tsc.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin#setting-up-typescript-server-logging
So here is what I tried:

I modified my build script in package.json, but no log file appeared after using it with npm run build. My code compiled correctly though.

{
  "script": {
    "build": "cross-env TSS_LOG=\"-logToFile true -file D:\\ts-server.log -level verbose\" tsc"
  }
}


Same with typing the following command in PowerShell, in Git Bash and in Command Prompt:

npx cross-env TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file D:\ts-server.log -level verbose" tsc


Same with trying to set the variable directly in PowerShell before running tsc

> $Env:TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file D:\ts-server.log -level verbose"
> npx tsc


Same with trying to set the variable directly in Git Bash before running tsc

$ TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file D:\ts-server.log -level verbose"
$ npx tsc


Same with trying to set the variable directly in Command Prompt before running tsc

> SET TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file D:\ts-server.log -level verbose"
> npx tsc


Same when using a slash instead of a backslash in the log file path for all of the above methods: D:/ts-server.log

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my setup:

Windows 11 Pro
Node 20.17.0, also tried with 18.20.4
TypeScript 5.5.4, also tried with 4.9.5

Update: I just tried on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with Node 20.11.1 and I cannot get a log either, so now I'm sure it is not OS related.

I dived into TypeScript's code and fount out tsc doesn't use TS Server to begin with. Then, looking back at the tutorial I linked in the question, I realized its about plugins meant to be tested and used on VS Code (maybe on other IDEs too).
So, to answer my question:

It's not possible to get a TS Server log using tsc
To set TSS_LOG properly on Windows 11, you have to go through Settings > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...


I think you use :
set TSS_LOG=-logToFile true -file D:\ts-server.log -level verbose

npx tsc

or
Using cross-env in package.json:
  {
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env TSS_LOG=\"-logToFile true -file D:/ts-server.log -level verbose\" tsc"
  }
}


The first one would be a Command Prompt equivalent of what I did in Powershell and Git Bash, as stated in my question. The second one would be the build script I used, but using a slash instead of backslashes. I tried both, just to be sure, but as expected, it didn't work. I'll edit my question to include those tries.

maybe this Command support you?
'rm -rf node_modules
npm install' or check '$Env:TSS_LOG
'

No, the tests are performed on minimal, freshly installed projects. I checked the environment with $Env:TSS_LOG, echo "$TSS_LOG" and echo %TSS_LOG% depending on the terminal. They showed TSS_LOG was properly set.
